# Get value from Json object (url) in php

Tags: php, json

I have a json i am fetching remotely in php,
the Json returned is as follow:

```
{
   "base_currency_code":"USD",
   "base_currency_name":"United States dollar",
   "amount":"1.0000",
   "updated_date":"2022-01-30",
   "rates":{
      "KWD":{
         "currency_name":"Kuwaiti dinar",
         "rate":"0.3030",
         "rate_for_amount":"0.3030"
      }
   },
   "status":"success"
}
```

the i try to get the specific value from key : rate :

```
$url='https://...';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
echo $obj['rates']['KWD']['rate'];
```

but I have no output, when I would like to have 0.3030. Why is this?

Comment: Do `var_dump($json);` before `json_encode()` and then `var_dump($obj);` after the json_encode(). What do you get?

Answer (score 2):

test.json

```
{
   "base_currency_code":"USD",
   "base_currency_name":"United States dollar",
   "amount":"1.0000",
   "updated_date":"2022-01-30",
   "rates":{
      "KWD":{
         "currency_name":"Kuwaiti dinar",
         "rate":"0.3030",
         "rate_for_amount":"0.3030"
      }
   },
   "status":"success"
}
```

test.php

```
<?php 
$url='test.json';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
echo $obj['rates']['KWD']['rate'];
```

Result 0.3030

If it is not working, you cannot access the site remotely.

try it and make sure it works

```
<?php 
$url='https......';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
echo $json;
```